# React Redirect redirects to wrong path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Index.js

```
<div className='col'>
  <label htmlFor='link'> Link: </label>
  <input type="text" name="link" id="link" className="form-control" readOnly value={ link } />  ===>>Link is something like https:www.google.com
</div>
```

Route.js

```
{ path: '/recommendation-edit/:id', name:'Recommendation Edit', component: RekkoEdit }
```

I want if someone clicks on link that it redirects to that link. I have tried `Link` to and `Redirect`, but they didn't work as expected. If I use any of them it redirects to

```
http://localhost:3000/recommendation-detail/https://www.amazon.in/dp/B08445DF23/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_apa_i_RPBvFb596RQVR
```

whereas it need to redirect to

```
https://www.amazon.in/dp/B08445DF23/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_apa_i_RPBvFb596RQVR
```

Answer (score 2):

React router as its name suggests is used for routing React apps. What you are looking for is plain old anchor element. So simply use:

`<a href={link}>link</a>`

instead of `Link`